# Deriving the Laurent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

How do I derive the Laurent series

$$\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(n-1)}{(z-1)^n}$$

from $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)z^n$$

It looks like I can do some sort of substitution $$z'=\frac{1}{z-1}$$

however I cannot simply to the result.

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: You need to be aware of at which point you are doing the Laurent expansion. And I think you made a mistake somewhere in the first equation, as $\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic at $z = 1$. Even at $z = 0$ it is a pole of degree $2$. The RHS is an essential singularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\left\vert z - 1\right\vert < 1$:
$$
{1 \over z^{2}}
=
{1 \over \left[1 - \left(1 - z\right)\right]^{2}}
=
\left.{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}z'}\left(1 \over 1 - z'\right)
\right\vert_{z'\ =\ 1 - z}
=
\left.{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}z'}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z'^{n}
\right\vert_{z'\ =\ 1 - z}
$$